# Reason behind using (void)someInt; in code

Tags: c++

I am reading some code of a library I am using, and I found that in a function this was used:

```
void someFunction(Foo& a, int index, int partId)
{
    (void) partId;
    (void) index;
    // more code
}
```

Anyone knows why? Thanks.

Comment: `partId` and `index` were unused and this is a way to evaluate them in order to bypass warnings regarding unused parameters.

Comment: Someone doesn't know to write `void someFunction(Foo &a, int, int)` which would avoid the 'unused argument' warnings that the `(void)partId` statements avoid.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Or the more charitable explanation is that the developer knows what they are dong and that they are place-holders for future development of the code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To avoid a compiler warning/error indicating that the variable was unused in the function body. It's a style choice, the other way to achieve the same effect would be to leave the variable un-named:

```
void someFunction(Foo& a, int /*index*/, int /*partId*/)
```

Comment: That is how I am doing it as well. I think it is cleaner. Any reason not to it that way?

Comment: Only stylistic - the (void) method is based on the fact that it produces no instructions, but it seems to me that someone could actually construct an object such that it does have side effects and so actually emits a call to an operator, but I haven't tried to prove that :)

Comment: @KitFisto: The version using a cast works in C. Leaving out the name on the parameter only works in C++.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Ah, didnt know that. But not relevant for me either ;-)

Answer (score 3):

This is usually done when the parameters aren't being used in the function and the compiler emits a warning about unused parameters. By adding the case the compiler will deem that they have been used and not issue the waring.

You can accomplish the same thing my just removing the name of the parameter from the function:

```
void someFunction(Foo& a, int, int)
{
}
```

Comment: From my expirience removing the name from the function creates alot of confusion later, as the previous intent of the parameter is lost, and you will have to work alot harder to understand what it was meant for in the first place...

Comment: @user1708860 - I agree, I've just put it here for illustration. This isn't such an issue in a method as the decleration in the class has all the parameters, but the implementation can omit them if they're not required.

Comment: The usual reason for having the unnamed parameter is because the function conforms to some interface that requires 3 parameters, but this particular implementation of the interface doesn't use the information from two of the parameters.  Callbacks, and related concepts.

Answer (score 1):

`Index` and `partId` are not used inside the function.

A C/C++ compiler will usually throw a warning about unused parameters.

the `(void) parameter;` statement will not generate any code, but let the compiler know you are using the parameter, in order to avoid the said warning.

It is also a polite way to let another programmer know easily that the parameters are unused for some reason
(typically, complying with a more generic interface or supporting obsolete parameters from a previous version of the same interface).

Last but not least, as Jerry Coffin pointed out, this works both in C and C++, while the alternative solution of using unnamed parameters only works in C++.

Answer (score 0):

What it does is to *use* `partId` and `index`, without actually using them. In other words, it fools the compiler into thinking that the function arguments are actually used, while in reality the code doesn't use them.

Why would one do that? Because they have set a flag in the compiler to generate a warning when an argument of a function is not used in its body.

Note that in C++, one can simply remove the argument name from the function. If you see that in C, try disabling warning on unused function arguments since you can't omit argument names.

Comment: And why setting this flag is bad exactly? Imagine function void foo(int x, int y); You're tired and you write x instead of y in the body, y becomes unused. The warning will gives you a free debug. This is not a "bad compiler flag", this is a "good compiler flag".

Comment: @ThePluc, imagine a callback given to a function that takes a `void *extra` argument that you don't want to use. However, it makes sense to keep the name of the argument to be clear what the argument was. Admittedly though, I'm used to C giving an error if you omit a parameter name.

Comment: I didn't say it was the preferred solution, I never use this. But it is certainly not better to disable the warning. I personnaly comment the parameter names or use a compiler specific option such as __attribute__((unused)) for gcc (and CLang I assume)